Android test class with time delay
I'm working on an IdleHandler class in my Android app to handle inactivity. The class looks like this:
        class IdleHandler {
            object TimerConstants {
                const val DEFAULT_POPUP_COUNTER = 20
                const val DEFAULT_CLOSE_COUNTER = 15
                const val TIME_DELAY_MILLIS = 1000L
            }

            private val _popupCounter = MutableStateFlow(DEFAULT_POPUP_COUNTER)
            private val _closeCounter = MutableStateFlow(DEFAULT_CLOSE_COUNTER)
            private val popupCounter: StateFlow<Int> = _popupCounter.asStateFlow()
            val closeCounter: StateFlow<Int> = _closeCounter.asStateFlow()
            private var isAlertShown: Boolean = true

            suspend fun start(showAlert: Boolean = true) {
                isAlertShown = showAlert

                while (true) {
                    delay(TIME_DELAY_MILLIS)
                    when {
                        countersEnded() -> break
                        popupCounter.value > 0 -> decreasePopupCounter()
                        closeCounter.value > 0 -> decreaseCloseCounter()
                    }
                }
            }

            fun isAlertShown(): Boolean {
                return isAlertShown
            }

            private fun decreaseCloseCounter() {
                _closeCounter.update { it.minus(1) }
            }

            private fun decreasePopupCounter() {
                _popupCounter.update { it.minus(1) }
            }

            fun resetCounters() {
                _popupCounter.update { DEFAULT_POPUP_COUNTER }
                _closeCounter.update { DEFAULT_CLOSE_COUNTER }
            }

            fun popupCounterEnded(): Boolean = _popupCounter.value < 1

            fun countersEnded(): Boolean = _closeCounter.value < 1 && _popupCounter.value < 1
        }

I'm trying to test it like this, making the time jumps. Using mockito and junit
      @Test
        fun testStart() = runTest {
            idleHandler.start()
            assertTrue(idleHandler.popupCounterEnded()) // this should fail
            advanceTimeBy(
                IdleHandler.TimerConstants.DEFAULT_CLOSE_COUNTER *
                    IdleHandler.TimerConstants.TIME_DELAY_MILLIS
            )
            assertTrue(idleHandler.countersEnded())
        }


However, this test fails completely. The first assertTrue(idleHandler.popupCounterEnded()) fails.
Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Information:
I'm using Kotlin coroutines and the StateFlow API for managing the counters.
The advanceTimeBy function is supposed to simulate the passage of time.
I'm using the latest versions of Mockito and JUnit.
